# Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'fasttext' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, fasttext

I want to use the FastText.NetWrapper library in my project. I imported the library and wrote the sample code, but after running it, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'fasttext' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable:
  dlopen(/Users/a/Desktop/Spell Corrector/MyMLNetProject/bin/Debug/net7.0/runtimes/osx-arm64/native/fasttext.dylib, 0x0001):
 tried:
 '/Users/a/Desktop/Spell Corrector/MyMLNetProject/bin/Debug/net7.0/runtimes/osx-arm64/native/fasttext.dylib' (no such file),
 '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/a/Desktop/Spell Corrector/MyMLNetProject/bin/Debug/net7.0/runtimes/osx-arm64/native/fasttext.dylib' (no such file),
 '/Users/a/Desktop/Spell Corrector/MyMLNetProject/bin/Debug/net7.0/runtimes/osx-arm64/native/fasttext.dylib' (no such file)
```

I'm sure I installed the library correctly.I'm posting a code for an example.

```cs
using FastText.NetWrapper;
using System;

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

        using (var classifier = new FastTextWrapper())
        {
           
            classifier.Supervised("train.txt", "model");
    
         
            string testText = "Bu bir test metnidir.";
    
        
            var result = classifier.PredictSingle(testText);
    
           
            Console.WriteLine($"Tahmin edilen sınıf: {result.Label}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Tahmin edilen olasılık: {result.Probability}");
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone help about this?

I tried to train a model , it didn't work.

Comment: "I'm sure I installed the library correctly" describe how you are sure.

Comment: "dotnet add package FastText.NetWrapper" I used this command and thought it was enough, is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Is it supported on osx-arm64?

Comment: A library usually has more documentation on how to acquire and deploy native dependencies (beyond .NET assemblies). So `dotnet add package` is just the start.

Comment: @Charlieface I don't know about this. There is no information about this in the documentation.

Comment: @LexLi I followed the documentation steps, it did not say that I needed to do an extra step, maybe the problem occurred because I was working on a Mac.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - this kind of questions tends arrise from lack of knowledge on stack trace reading, first gain some knowledge on code compile flow, libraries linking  and debugging then go to coding

Comment: @ceph3us Thank you for your comment, but I think I have enough information, I use this website to get help on the missing parts and I think everyone is here for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to use dotnet on Mac, there may be problems with the path of the libraries. If you change the path of the file to

> /usr/local/lib

, the problem will be solved, but for this you need to turn off SIP security. This solved my problem.